# How to touch the overflow button in calabash-android?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-testing, calabash, calabash-android

I'm trying to touch on the overflow button in my app using calabash-android testing. after so much of research i found a method to touch the overflow button.

```
tap_when_element_exists("android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView")
```

this worked for me when there was only one overflow button in screen and no other buttons. But for a screen like the picture below, which has overflow button and other buttons above method is not working. I tried with index also,

```
tap_when_element_exists("android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView index:0"),
tap_when_element_exists("android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView index:1")
```

, etc but still not solved.

Then i used this method-

```
select_options_menu_item("* id:'action_change_notification'")
```

but when i used this method, the overflow button is invoked but cannot touch the items in it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a better solution. and it works perfectly.

This could give you the overflow menu button in the screen.

```
query("android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton")

tap_when_element_exists("android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `query("android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView")` and see how many elements you get, then identify the one you need, maybe by `'id'` or `'content-description'` which should be unique.

You could try using the `uiautomator` from your Android SDK. It's a very helpful tool to identify elements and see the hierarchy.

Usually located in your sdk folder under `\tools\bin`. You will see something like this:

[image]

Now you could go through the children of that ListView in order to access what is needed, something like this (used above image as example):

`query("android.widget.ListView android.widget.LinearLayout id:'title'")`

Let me know if it worked, there might be other ways.

Comment: i appreciate you for helping me, i have not tested whether it works. soon i will check and let you know.